# (Hall's Theorem) Existence of two subfamilies of sets containing the same elements

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I came across the following claim in a textbook on combinatorics [1].

> **Claim (Lindström, Tverberg):** Let $A_1, . . . , A_m \subseteq [n]$ be non-empty with $m > n$. There are non-empty, disjoint $I, J \subseteq [m]$, such
> that $$\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcup_{j \in J} A_j.$$

The book provides a very nice proof of this claim, using characteristic vectors of the sets $A_1, . . . , A_m$ and some linear algebra basics.

It also includes a remark that says this claim can be proved using [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). This second approach is not obvious to me but I would like to understand how you can use Hall's theorem here (it's really bugging me). If anyone could provide a solution, a hint, or a reference to a proof, I would really appreciate it.

Reference:
[1] B. Sudakov, "Algebraic Methods in Combinatorics", 2023

> **Original Proof:** Let $v_1, . . . , v_m$ be the characteristic vectors of $A_1, . . . , A_m$. Since $m>n$, they are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$. So, there is a nonzero $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^m$ with $$\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i v_i = 0.$$ Let $$I = \{i : \alpha_i > 0\},$$
> $$J=\{j : \alpha_j < 0\}.$$ The nonzero coordinates of $\sum\limits_{i \in I} \alpha_i v_i$ correspond to the
> elements of $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$, which are the same as the nonzero coordinates of $\sum\limits_{j \in J} \alpha_j v_j$ corresponding to $\bigcup\limits_{j \in J} A_j$, completing the proof.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151891/discussion-on-question-by-matth-halls-theorem-existence-of-two-subfamilies-of); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a partial response, here is a proof of the claim based on a possible *proof* of Hall's theorem. Maybe it will inspire further progress.

The graph we consider is the usual graph for the system-of-representatives view of the theorem: let $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m\}$, $Y = \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\}$, and put an edge $x_i y_j$ whenever $j \in A_i$. It will be important that because the $A_i$ are all nonempty, $X$ has no isolated vertices.

Pick a maximum matching $M$ in this graph. Of course, since $m>n$, this matching does not cover all of $X$. We are going to start by letting $U_0$ be the set of all vertices in $X$ not covered by $M$, and then repeat the following procedure:

1. After $U_i$ has been defined, let $V_i = N(U_i) - N(U_0 \cup \dots \cup U_{i-1})$: the set of "new" vertices in $Y$, which are adjacent to $U_i$ that we haven't found previously.
2. Let $U_{i+1}$ be the set of all vertices in $X$ matched to $V_i$ by $M$.

We stop when no new vertices get added to $U_0, U_1, U_2, \dots$ or $V_0, V_1, V_2, \dots$.

How is this related to Hall's theorem? Well, every vertex in $V_i$ has a path to it from $U_0$, a path zigzagging between the sets $$U_0 - V_0 - U_1 - V_1 \dots - U_i - V_i$$ in which every $V-U$ type edge is an edge of the matching. So if we ever find an *unmatched* vertex in $V_i$, this zigzagging path is an augmenting path that could be used to improve $M$. Since $M$ is assumed to be a maximum matching, no such augmenting path exists. Therefore every vertex in $V_i$ is matched by $M$; it follows that $|V_i| = |U_{i+1}|$. The procedure can only stop by having $V_i = \varnothing$ at some stage, and it must stop since our graph is finite.

At this point, we normally say that $S = U_0 \cup U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_{i+1}$ is a subset of $X$ with $N(S) = V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \dots \cup V_i$, and $|S| = |U_0| + |N(S)|$, so $S$ is a set violating Hall's condition. This proves the hard direction of Hall's theorem.

What we'll say here instead is that if we take $S_0 = U_0 \cup U_2 \cup U_4 \cup \dots$ and $S_1 = U_1 \cup U_3 \cup U_5 \cup \dots$ (even-numbered sets in $S_0$, and odd-numbered sets in $S_1$), then $N(S_0) = N(S_1) = N(S)$. That's because each vertex in $V_i$ has a neighbor in $U_i$ (that's how we got it) and a neighbor in $U_{i+1}$ (which it was matched to by $M$). The sets $S_0$ and $S_1$ are exactly what we're looking for in this question. (To relate them back to the theorem we want, we let $I = \{i \in [m] : x_i \in S_0\}$ and $J = \{j \in [m] : x_j \in S_1\}$.)

Unfortunately, I don't see how to use just the statement of Hall's theorem (and not the proof) to make this deduction. It's not clear *a priori* why a set $S \subseteq X$ with $|N(S)|<|S|$ must split into disjoint sets $S_0, S_1$ with $N(S_0) = N(S_1) = N(S)$, even though we see it happening here.

We still learn one useful thing from this argument: the existence of $S_0$ and $S_1$ follows not just if $m>n$, but whenever the graph has no perfect matching. And *this* useful fact is a consequence of Hall's theorem (as well as the theorem in the question): if we find a set $S$ with $|N(S)|<|S|$, we can apply the theorem in the question to just the sets $A_i$ with $x_i \in S$, and just the elements $j \in [n]$ with $y_j \in N(S)$.

Comment: Here's a way you could use Hall's theorem in your proof. Make it a proof by induction on $n$. You can assume that $|N(A)|\ge|A|$ whenever $A\subseteq[m]$ and $|A|\le n$, as otherwise you can use the inductive hypothesis with $A$ and $N(A)$ replacing $X$ and $Y$. Then by Hall's theorem your matching $M$ covers $Y$, so you don't need the augmenting path.